# Passing decisional param to @TestConfiguration class

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

I would like to send a parameter to @Bean in @TestConfiguration class to return diffrent AnimalType depends of the string which comes in the parameter. Is it possible to do it from a test class or I need a diffrent Config for each class?

```
@TestConfiguration
public class TestConfig {

       @Bean
       public AnimalType componentType(String type) {
          return new AnimalType(type);
       }

}
```

It could be achieved also by constructo injection but it's also not possible to call @TestConfig constructor with parameter which is not a bean;

Answer (score 0):

You could read the `type` from a property like this:

```
@Component
public class AnimalType {

    @Value("${animal.type}")
    private String value;
}
```

and then in your test specify it with `@SpringBootTest(properties = { "animal.type=dog" })`.